# Laravel: Paginate listed users

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I have a Laravel aplication, with standard Authentication implemented. 
I would like to get the paginated list of the users in a table, but I get this error:

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method paginate does not exist.

Here is the code:

```
$users = User::all()->paginate(25);
```

If I use this without calling the paginate() method, everything works well.
Am I doing something wrong?
I searched a lot, but I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$users = User::paginate(25);
```

The thing is `paginate()` is kind of doing `get()` for you. And `all()` does it too.

Comment: You're my saver! :) 
Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Comment: Why is this difference between the usage with other models and the User model?

Comment: I don't think there's any difference. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any where condition ? You can use this easily

```
$perPage = 25;
$users = User::where('age', '20');
return $users->paginate($perPage);
```